# How to configure shortcut key for windows 8 apps

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts

I know there is few shortcut key on Windows 8 (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to logout, <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> for right menu), but how can I add or update shortcuts key for Windows Store app (News, Contacts...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Locate the application’s shortcut icon. If it isn’t already on your desktop / taskbar, use Explorer’s search feature to query for it.
2. Right click the shortcut and select properties.
3. Enter a key combo in the Shortcut key field. The combo must be <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + a third key such as a letter or number.
4. Click OK.

link with pictures: http://windows8tabs.com/windows-8-apps-how-to-create-keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why I couldn't find it before ;)

Comment: You are more than welcome!