# How to configure shortcut key for windows 8 apps (and shutdown maybe)

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any way to configure Windows 8 to shutdown by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> or something? I need it for other Windows Store apps also (News, Contacts...)
If there are already some shortcuts where I find them?

Comment: I'm not sure if this belong to SU :/

Comment: The idea Microsoft has for shutdown in Windows 8: press the power button.

Comment: [How do I shutdown windows 8?](http://superuser.com/questions/491008/how-do-i-shutdown-windows-8/491049#491049) & [What are the new shortcuts for Windows 8](http://superuser.com/questions/466789/what-are-the-new-shortcuts-for-windows-8/492495#492495) are most probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can shutdown by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> and confirming with <kbd>Enter</kbd>  or by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> use arrow keys to select **Settings** and than **Power**.
2. You could make a shutdown shortcut, and assigning it a your own keyboard shortcut (I have answered you [Win8: how to make a keyboard shortcut](https://superuser.com/questions/505261/how-to-configure-shortcut-key-for-windows-8-apps/505269#505269).
   Here is a link describing [how to make a shutdown shortcut](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/quick-tip-create-shutdown-restart-lock-icons-in-windows-vista/), to which you can assign your own keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Yes, I made this question on SO before, but I found the answer here and them I just asked for the keyboard shortcuts ;)